# Return the generic object, from a generic object

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

```
public class ClassWithGeneric<T>
{
}

public class SecondClassWithGeneric<U>
{
    public void getNestedObject()
    {
        //How do I get the type of object T?
    }
}

public class TestProgram
{
   var nestedGenerics = new SecondClassWithGeneric<ClassWithGeneric<ObjectToLoad>>;  
}

public class ObjectToLoad
{
}
```

The question is how do I get the type of object T? in this case it would return "ObjectToLoad".

Comment: Incomplete. You don't specify a real connection between ClassWithGeneric and SecondClassWithGeneric.

Comment: @HenkHolterman, they're nested?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should give you the type `ObjectToLoad` but it's also highly prone to error.

```
public class SecondClassWithGeneric<U>
{
    public void getNestedObject()
    {
         var type = typeof(U).GetGenericArguments()[0];
    }
}
```

Comment: Right, but is that not one `.GetGenericArguments()[0]` too many?

Comment: Yes, one _could_ start from `typeof(SecondClassWithGeneric<U>)`, but it is easier to start `typeof(U)` like you do. Since .NET 4.5, there is also `typeof(U).GenericTypeArguments[0]`. In both cases one should check the length of the array before doing attempting to read the 0th entry.

Answer (score 3):

Not very clear but probably:

```
public class SecondClassWithGeneric<U, T> 
         where U : ClassWithGeneric<T>   
{
    public T getNestedObject()
    {
        //How do I get the type of object T?
    }
}
```

or maybe

```
public class SecondClassWithGeneric<U, T> 
{
    public ClassWithGeneric<T> getNestedObject()
    {
        //How do I get the type of object T?
    }
}
```